# Customize Shopware 6 invoice PDF

Tags: pdf, templating, shopware, shopware6

I'll change the template of the invoice pdf template in shopware 6.
The template self seems to be stored in the database in the table "document".
The pdf is generated by php.
Anyone knows, how to get a complete own customized template ?
The configuration in the backend is not enough.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote an example Theme some time ago, that is extending the basic template: https://github.com/mnaczenski/SwagDocumentTemplate

The core template is located here:https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Framework/Resources/views/documents/base.html.twig

So you can overwrite the file in your own theme like described in the documentation by extending the twig file and placing it in the right folder: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/themes/theme-base-guide

Extend in Twig: `{% sw_extends '@Framework/documents/base.html.twig' %}`
Folder structure: `/src/Resources/views/documents/base.html.twig`

Generated PDFs are stored in the database due to German law, they can't be changed after generation. But new generated PDFs are based on the template.

Comment: Thank you mnaczenski. The .twig's are not the problem. I look to change the layout of an pdf or create a complete new one.

Comment: The twig will be used to create the pdf - so the twig will create html and dompdf is used to create a pdf out of the html. So this is definitely the right point to change the layout of the pdf.

Comment: Okay. I can change the mail templates but can't found how to change the PDF layout. i created a new plugin and stored a invoice.html.twig in MindInvoiceTemplate\src      \Resources\views\documents\invoice.html.twig, cleared the cache but without results.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to customize your invoice templates is to use the [WYSIWYG Document Editor](https://store.shopware.com/appli81810362453/wysiwyg-dokumenten-editor-pdf-rechnungen-lieferscheine-gutschriften-stornos-designen.html). You can either customize an existing document or create a completely new document. Using one of the predefined document templates provides a good starting point for you to apply your customizations. But you can also start with a blank page.

With the visual editor, you can easily add new elements and variables and see your changes in the live preview. This will save you a lot of time in comparison to going back and forth hundreds of times between making adjustments in your Twig Files and generating new PDFs for testing.

[image: Add new elements to your documents in Shopware 6 via drag & drop with ease]

Here is a YouTube Video, which shows you how easy and fast you can edit all your documents: https://youtu.be/fGBMDmVMPvA

I am the developer, which created the [WYSIWYG Document Editor Shopware 6 App](https://store.shopware.com/appli81810362453/wysiwyg-dokumenten-editor-pdf-rechnungen-lieferscheine-gutschriften-stornos-designen.html). Feel free to ask me any questions about the App. I am happy to help you.

Comment: thank you, but i dont need commercials.

Comment: But i think it will help a lot of others.